# Avoid to require vendor/autoload.php in every file

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I'm currently learning about autoload in php using composer and psr-4. i have successfully configured my composer.json and i can access classes using namespaces. Now, the problem is that i have to include vendor/autoload.php in every file that i want to use it in. It looks like this because of the structure  i have in my project:

`require("../../../vendor/autoload.php");`

Is there a cleaner way to do this or avoid requiring it in every file?

I have tried with some things like creating a Global variable with that route, but it is not working. This is what i tried:

At the start of my index.php:
`$GLOBAL["autoloadPath"]= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ipa-crm/vendor/autoload.php';`

Then i added this in every file that i needed:
`require_once $GLOBAL["autoloadPath"];`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you've tried $GLOBALS instead of $GLOBAL?

Comment: Lesson learned, whatever you do will be a hack.. next time have a single entry point and use namespacing to autoload your logic through a router, instead of many individual files.

Answer (score 3):

Using the configuration `auto_prepend_file` in `.htaccess`, you can automatically prepend a PHP file to all requested PHP files. Just put it into your `.htaccess` like this:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/file/before.php"
php_value auto_append_file "/path/to/file/after.php"
```

Comment: Thank you! i tried this and it worked. But instead,i did it in my php.ini file by adding auto_prepend_file and the route to the file. Now, my other question would be: doing this is safe?

Comment: @AugustoNuñez what do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: I feel it is not good to prepend/append files, because that affects every scripts even though they did not require vendor autoload.

Comment: @BimalPoudel I did not say that this prepend feature is a good one, but the OPs request was clearly to prepend something to **all** files without any exception

Answer (score 1):

I would say the most recommended way is having one single file that will load all other files and this files will load all other files depending on current action.

So you have `index.php` file with content similar to this (this is obviously very simplified):

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

switch ($_GET['url']) {
    case 'contact':
       require __DIR__.'/../pages/contact.php';
       break;
    case '':
       require __DIR__.'/../pages/main.php';
       break;
   default:
      require __DIR__.'/../pages/404.php';
}
```

And you also have `.htaccess` file with mod rewrite enabled with such content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)(.*)/?$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

So now all traffic will go through `index.php` and you can require Composer autoloader only in this single file.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of different solutions possible. Cleanest way is to use require_once within config file only, where you have your own set of vendor folder for each project. But there is an advanced option on localhost, or the server that allows to reconfigure php.ini:

Modify your php.ini to append a custom path that points to composer's global path. Then write:

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
```

Make sure you do not use local vendor directory, or just ensure that your composer has defined everything locally. I mean, presence of local **./vendor** directory is optional. The **"./"** which is missing in my example will allow PHP to look for global path. Then, always use your composer globally (passing **global** as additional parameter when you install a composer library.

Your **php.ini** may look like:

```
include_path = "C:/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/Composer"
```

Thus, vendor/autload.php is always available to any php files, if they call require_once "vendor/autoload.php". Hopefully, you will use it once in your config file for the entire project, and not from individual scripts.

Comment: How does this help to avoid using `require_once` in every script?